# Name Constraints, empty sets in permitted subtree (RFC 3280 vs RFC 5280)

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509, rfc

I'm trying to understand the effect of empty sets in `permittedSubtrees` in both, [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280) and [RFC 3280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3280). There is something that doesn't compile in my head.

**Scenario:**

We have a CA certificate with the following Name Constraints setup:

```
Permitted
     [1]Subtrees (0..Max):
          RFC822 Name=email@example.com
     [2]Subtrees (0..Max):
          DNS Name=
```

The setup has an empty set for `dnsName` name type. [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280) is more clear on this and §6.1.1 (h), §6.1.2 (b), §6.1.3 (b) and §6.1.4 (g) suggests that any issued certificate by this CA with `dnsName` name type in SAN extension are considered non-valid.

Here are my understandings:

1. There is an obvious difference between absent subtree and explicit empty set. In first case, (as per initialization in §6.1.2 (b)), a default value `permit all` is assigned to the absent subtree. In second case, default value is overridden with explicit empty set.
2. In a given setup, no `dnsName` name types are allowed in issued certificates.
3. any `iPAddress` name type is allowed in issued certificates.

If my understanding of RFC 5280 in this regard is correct, then my main question: what is the expected behavior for this setup against RFC 3280? The main difference is that RFC 3280 doesn't include §6.1.1 (h) where empty set behavior is explicitly defined. Does this section absence allows free interpretation of empty set behavior?

p.s. The question is related to Name Constraints validation in Windows client. Windows client successfully validate leaf certificate with `dnsName` name type despite that issuer defines an empty set for this name type. I have a support ticket with Microsoft, however the process is extremely slow (10 months atm) and their only helpful answer is that Windows client is written against RFC 3280 and Microsoft claims that the absence of §6.1.1 (h) allowed them to freely treat this behavior.

Comment: Did Microsoft made a public ticket about it? Basing an answer on an RFC that was obsoleted 14 years ago is something... 
Also did you survey what other implementation do (e.g. OpenSSL, GnuTLS)?  My interpretation of the RFC 5280 text is the same as yours for what it's worth...

Comment: `that was obsoleted 14 years ago is something...` we still have to consider. Microsoft product support policy is much longer. For example, their 15yr old Windows Server 2008 is still on ESU support.

Comment: No, I didn't survey other tools, as my concern is Windows client behavior.

Comment: Well possibly my answer will help. The CA/Browser forum touches the issue and says to do something that is in my view a lot less logical than what you did. But they do address the issue...

Comment: @BrunoRohée unfortunately your answer doesn't help since it is about CAB Forum, while my question is more about particular RFC.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging, and The CA/Brower Forum, of which [Microsoft is a member](https://cabforum.org/members/),  suggests another way of doing it, that doesn't sound very logical. The [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.8.4.pdf) have the following blurb in [*§7.1.5 Name constraints*](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.8.4.pdf#page=85):

> If the Subordinate CA is not allowed to issue certificates with `dNSNames`, then the Subordinate CA Certificate MUST include a zero‐length `dNSName` in `excludedSubtrees`. Otherwise, the Subordinate CA Certificate MUST include at least one `dNSName` in `permittedSubtrees`.

Your certificate layout would be in contradiction of that.

But a footnote in the Baseline Requirements shows that the CA/Browser Forum has little illusion about any of it working correctly, as the baseline requirements allow non critical `nameConstraints` in violation of RFC 5280 [with the note](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.8.4.pdf#page=74)

> Non‐critical Name Constraints are an exception to [RFC 5280 (4.2.1.10)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10), however, they MAY be used until the Name Constraints extension is supported by Application Software Suppliers whose software is used by a substantial portion of Relying Parties worldwide

Comment: The first version of this comment understood the reverse of what is actually written, I may be dumb but I can't shake the feeling that the CABForum way of doing it is very illogical.

Comment: I don't think that CA/B Forum is relevant to my question, because CA/B forum requirements doesn't apply to non-public CAs. That's why I'm focusing on RFC interpretation only.

Comment: Well while in theory it isn't, in practice it's what is driving the evolution of x.509/TLS stacks, so whatever decisions they take will spill out on the whole ecosystem.